# Wrong day when using day()-formula with format - PowerBI

Tags: date, powerbi, days

I'm trying to find out the weekday i.e Mon, Tue, Wed etc. from a date-range formatted as yyyy mm dd

I tried to use the formula `format(day(Date Table),"ddd")`, but the weekday is wrong. In my example, the output of 2020.01.01 gives Sunday, but it should be Wednesday.

[image: Date Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the DAY function in DAX, it returns the day of the month (1 through 31).

Thus `DAY ( DATE ( 2020, 1, 1) ) = 1` which means you're trying to format the number `1` as a date. Integers are interpreted as days since 1899/12/30 when treated as a date, so `1` corresponds to 1899/12/31, which happened to be a Sunday. Thus `FORMAT(1, "ddd") = "Sun"`.

There's no reason to get DAY involved here. You can simply write

```
Day = FORMAT ( 'Calendar'[Date], "ddd" )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your formula is wrong:

Instead of

```
format(day(Date Table),"ddd")
```

Use

```
format(<Target Table>[<date column>],"ddd")
```

I.e. Omit the [DAX DAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/day-function-dax) call. This is resulting in the day of the month (1..31) being passed to the format function.